# Is there an integration between projectile and python-mode that allows for one python interpreter buffer per projectile project?

Tags: python, projectile

I use projectile with python (and anaconda mode) to work in emacs. When starting an ipython interpreter buffer, the first such session works fine. However, attempting to start a second session, for example, to have another project-specific shell, results in the commands from the second project being sent to the first project's python interpreter. Renaming python interpreter buffers seems to work at least sometimes, but I have not figured out how to specify on a per-project basis which interpreter buffer to use, even when renamed. I am aiming for the emacs/python equivalent of the ESS/R experience, which enables and works well with project-specific interpreter buffers. Any suggestions?

FYI, this was also posted to [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/9x75t0/any_recommendations_for_projectilepython/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, I ended up using directory-local variables to set a project-specific python buffer name. This works well enough. Details are available in [this post](https://seandavi.github.io/2018/12/using-directory-local-variables-to-customize-the-emacs-project-experience/).